# All versions of IE return SCRIPT5007 Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, debugging

I have the following code:

```
$('.sublime-typer').each(function() {
    var maximum = $(this).attr('data-terminal');
    for (var j = 1; j <= maximum; j++) {
        var $el = $('.sublime-typer[data-terminal="' + j + '"]'),
            txt = $el.html(),
            txtLen = txt.length,
            timeOut,
            char = 0,
            drawValue = 1;

        $el.text('|');

        (function typeIt() {
            var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (2 - 50)) + 30;
            timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
                char++;
                var type = txt.substring(0, char);

                if (type.indexOf('data-compiled="true-' + drawValue + '"') >= 0) {
                    var currentClass = $('.drawValue-' + drawValue).attr('class');
                    $('.drawValue-' + drawValue).attr('class', currentClass + ' activated');
                    $('.drawValue-' + drawValue).addClass('activated');

                    // For firefox as it doesn't support svg letter spacing :(
                    if( (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) && (drawValue == 2) ){
                        $('.drawValue-' + drawValue).attr('dx', '0 -3px')
                    }

                    drawValue = drawValue + 1;
                }

                $el.html(type + '|');
                typeIt();

                if (char == txtLen) {
                    $el.html($el.html().slice(0, -1)); // removes the '|'
                    clearTimeout(timeOut);
                }
            }, humanize);
        }());
    }
});
```

Which runs perfectly in all versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari, however on any version of IE it returns the error:
`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference.`
It doesn't make a difference if I have window.load or document.ready around the script and get the same error if I change `txtLen = txt.length,` to `txtLen = txt.val,` but with val instead of length in the error.

I have looked at a lot of other questions with the same SCRIPT5007 problem and none of the ones I've had a look at have worked.
Any help with this is very much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Created a Fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhruveshah/v8se7jnh/)

Comment: Can you verify that `$el` isn't empty? Maybe try declaring the variables on their own line, which semicolons (though your syntax is correct)?

Comment: if `$el` doesn't exist then `txt` will be undefined and you would get that error. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: what kind of element is `$el`? text input? div?

Comment: @doublesharp, how would it work on the other browsers if it was empty? I tried declaring the variables on their own lines but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @lucas `.sublime-typer` is an SVG text element

Comment: might be that IE doesn't return `html()` for that element. Issue is not hard to test in browser console

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your `.sublime-typer` elements is missing the data attribute `data-terminal`

Comment: I only have one `.sublime-typer` element, which is:
`<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 225 145)" class="sublime-typer" data-terminal="1" fill="white">`

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: Created a fiddle and added the link above as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/dhruveshah/v8se7jnh/

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
txt = $el.text(),
txtLen = txt.length,
//etc
```

Comment: I tried this, it removes the error on IE, but the purpose of the code also stops working, and on Safari, it strips out the inner html, and 'types' it in one line rather than in multiple lines
I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhruveshah/v8se7jnh/ to show what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SVG + IE = No fun.

The basic problem you are running into is that .html() returns 'undefined' in every case.

Change your instances of ".html()" to ".prop('textContent')", and from ".html(newval)" to ".prop('textContent', newval)".

If you make those changes, then you just need to solve the linebreak problem. Probably you should put some \r\n chars in where you want breaks, and textContent will retain them (as it strips the tSpans out generally).